# I want to use web-socket for server communication at client side.

Tags: angularjs, websocket

I want to use web-socket for server communication at client side. \

I am using AngularJS. I do not want to use HTML5 web-sockets.   Please help me out how to implement web-socket in AngularJS

Comment: Something like this? http://clintberry.com/2013/angular-js-websocket-service/

Comment: socket.io has everything you need

Comment: @z.a. don't forget you also need `NodeJS` for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular-websocket :

As this is one time activity, if angular-websocket is available in application library do not install it again.  If it is not avaiable please choose any one of the following option to install it.

(prefered) Using bower and running bower install angular-websocket --save
Using npm and running npm install angular-websocket --save
Downloading it manually by clicking here to download development unminified version
CDN for development https://rawgit.com/gdi2290/angular-websocket/v1.0.9/angular-websocket.js
CDN for production https://cdn.rawgit.com/gdi2290/angular-websocket/v1.0.9/angular-websocket.min.js

Usage:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-websocket/angular-websocket.js"></script>
  <section ng-controller="SomeController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="data in MyData.collection track by $index">
        {{ data }}
      </li>
    </ul>`enter code here`
  </section>
  <script>
    angular.module('YOUR_APP', [
      'ngWebSocket' // you may also use 'angular-websocket' if you prefer
    ])
    //                          WebSocket works as well
    .factory('MyData', function($websocket) {
      // Open a WebSocket connection
      var dataStream = $websocket('wss://website.com/data');

      var collection = [];

      dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
        collection.push(JSON.parse(message.data));
      });

      var methods = {
        collection: collection,
        get: function() {
          dataStream.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'get' }));
        }
      };

      return methods;
    })
    .controller('SomeController', function ($scope, MyData) {
      $scope.MyData = MyData;
    });
  </script>
```

Refrence:

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket